# Failed to start session Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, package-management, login, dpkg

The problem started when I tried to uninstall/install python2/python3. Terminal/Firefox were removed, I don't know how.

Then I rebooted the system.
Now, I am unable to login as the error was
[Failed to start session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHF6i.png)

I tried to upgrade and update through various commands like

```
sudo apt update
```

The message I am constantly getting is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWcMg.jpg)

Comment: `apt` like many other Ubuntu tools relies on python3 to work, so the moment you removed `python3` those tools that need it can no longer be used.  Your fix is to re-install the `python3-minimal` package, however you need to do so without using any tools that required `python3` to operate (eg. no `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude` etc).  ie. simple `wget` to download & `dpkg` to install as those tools are called by the user tools (`apt` etc) and don't need python.  Your text terminal will still work (though many GUI functions needing python3 will not)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have any network access in your second screen "could not resolve".
Try to plug the Ethernet cable or [I found this tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-ubuntu-18-04-19-04-with-wpa-supplicant) to use the wifi with command line and try again.
Otherwise you could also try to also check your DNS (and maybe replace it by 1.1.1.1 to try)

Let us know

Answer (score -1):

You killed off a critical service that all these others need. The quickest way to fix it and the most reliable is a fresh install.

Comment: Is there any other solution as fresh installation would be the least solution for each such problem

Comment: I have seen long involved answers as to how to repair python problems like yours but they always end with and this might not work re install. Why did you remove it in the first place?

Comment: I was having package conflict problem with the both version of Python2/3.6